# Image of $c_1: H^1(\mathbb CP^n, \mathcal O^*)\to H^2(\mathbb CP^n,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: complex-geometry, line-bundles

By the exact sequence $0\to \mathbb Z\to \mathcal O\to  \mathcal O^*\to0$ and $H^1(\mathbb CP^n, \mathcal O)=0$ we can get the injection $$\text {Pic}(\mathbb CP^n)\cong H^1(\mathbb CP^n, \mathcal O^*)\xrightarrow{c_1} H^2(\mathbb CP^n,\mathbb Z)\cong \mathbb Z$$

Since $H^2(\mathbb CP^n, \mathcal O)=\mathbb Z$, it is not clear if $c_1$ is surjective. But I heard the $c_1(\mathcal O_{\mathbb CP^n} (1))$ is the generator of $H^2(\mathbb CP^n,\mathbb Z)$. I wonder how to see this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the image of $c_1$ is killed by the map $H^2(\mathbb CP^n, \mathbb Z) \to H^2(\mathbb CP^n, \mathcal O)$, which is a map $\mathbb {Z\to Z}$.

However, such a map is either $0$ or injective.

If the map is $0$, then $c_1$ is surjective, and if the map is injective, then the image of $c_1$ (which is injective) is $0$ and so $H^1(\mathbb CP^n, \mathcal O^*) = 0$, which is absurd.

It follows that the map is $0$, and so $c_1$ is surjective.

EDIT : Ted Shifrin below suggests that actually $H^2(\mathbb CP^n, \mathcal O)=0$ (which seems more reasonable to me but as I explained I don't know nearly enough about complex geonetry to argue over that).

In that case, the fact that $c_1$ is surjective follows immediately from the exactnes of the sequence (note that in any case the amswer is only related to the long exact sequence)

Comment: Why can't the map $c_1:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$  be $1\mapsto n$?

Comment: I explained that : if $c_1$ is not surjective, then its image is killed by the map $\mathbb {Z\to Z}$: but that can't happen unless the image is trivial or $\mathbb Z$, otherwise we would get an injective map $\mathbb{Z/nZ} \to \mathbb Z$, but there $1$ would be sent to some element of order $n$ in $\mathbb Z$ : there aren't that many of those

Comment: Excuse me. $H^2(\Bbb CP^n,\mathcal O) = 0$. Please revise.

Comment: @TedShifrin : well I have to admit I don't know enough about cohomology to know that; but in any case if you are right, the problem is even simpler : the exact sequence automatically yields that $c_1$ is surjective. I gave the argument above because the question stated $H^2(\mathbb CP^n , \mathcal O) = \mathbb Z$.

Comment: I'm sorry. Very glib to post an answer so confidently — and not revise it — when you know nothing about sheaf cohomology and  cohomology of complex manifolds.

Comment: @TedShifrin : I gave the answer precisely because it had nothing to do with sheaf cohomology, only with the long exact sequence. Had it anything to do with the specifics of the computations, I wouldn't have. As for revision, I was hoping that the OP would see our exchange and comment on it, but you are right, I will edit